# Using CGImage to generate a low quality JPG from data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, cgimage

I have some code which loads a jpg from data and displays it in a UIImageView. Because this takes a second, I want to load a lower quality version of the image and display that while the full image is loading. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at [Image I/O](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH218-DontLinkElementID_6)

It lets you create a thumbnail from a source image and supports retrieving a thumbnail that may be embedded within the source image. JPG images often have a low quality thumbnail embedded within them.

Also, if loading the image is blocking your app, you should consider doing it on a background thread: [load uiimage from file using grand central dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692864/load-uiimage-from-file-using-grand-central-dispatch)

Comment: I am loading in the background, i just want something to show the user in the mean time. Thanks.